# Unir duas tabelas com PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho duas tabelas no banco de dados, uma listando as postagens realizadas e a outra dos usuários cadastrados.

Colunas que tenho na tabela das postagens:

```
ID || TEXTO || ID_USER ||
```

Colunas que tenho na tabela de usuários:

```
ID || NOME_USER || SENHA_USER||
```

Ao fazer uma postagem qualquer o sistema pega o `ID` do usuário que está realizando a postagem e registra os dados.

Só que to tendo problema pra trabalhar melhor com as duas tabelas, na verdade quero fazer uma associação entre ambas tabelas. Porque quero associar o `ID_USER` cadastrado na tabela de postagens e associar o `ID` ao nome do usuário.

Tentei fazer isso:

```
("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE ID_USER in (SELECT ID FROM users)")
```

Mas não deu certo.

No momento as postagens exibidas ficam assim:

> 3 disse :: Texto que o usuario de ID 3 postou

Mas quero que elas fiquem assim:

> Carlos disse :: Texto que o usuario de ID 3 postou

Esse é todo PHP que estou usando para exibir as postagens:

```
<?php
$rs = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY ID DESC ")->fetchAll();

$count = count($rs);
if($count == 0){ echo "Nada foi encontrado"; }else{

if(!$rs){
print_r($pdo->errorInfo());
}foreach ($rs as $res)
{   
?>

<?php echo $res['ID_USER'] ?> disse :: <?php echo $res['TEXTO'] ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `inner join` não seria melhor? Coloque o PHP que você tem

Comment: Eu li sobre o inner, só que não consigo aplicar de forma correta. o php ta bem simples. Vou editar a pergunta e colocar o php que to usando pra exibir

Comment: [code review] Ivan, indentação do código é essencial para deixar a lógica clara e de fácil entendimento. As funções [`printf`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.printf.php) e `sprintf` são perfeitas para dar saída a pequenos trechos de HTML e não ter que ficar abrindo e fechando o PHP. Eu reescreveria o código assim: http://pastebin.com/kYjPq3iV

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Faça um [**INNER JOIN**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6448/11549) das tabelas logo abaixo:

**Definição de INNER JOIN**: quando a tabela A possui em uma tabela B o mesmo código de sua relação. Nas tabelas abaixo o campo `ID` de users se **relaciona** com campo `ID_USER` da tabela posts, aonde formam um relacionamento 1 para Muitos (1 users pode ter vários post ou nenhum)

Tabela de Usuarios (`users`)

> **ID** || NOME_USER || SENHA_USER||

Tabela de Postagens (`posts`)

> ID || TEXTO || **ID_USER** ||

---

```
SELECT a.ID as USERID, a.NOME_USER, 
       b.ID as POSTID, b.TEXTO
FROM users a INNER JOIN posts b on
      (a.ID = b.ID_USER)
```

***Exemplo ONLINE:*** [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1187f/1)

---

***PHP***

```
<?php
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=genericdb;host=localhost', 'root', 'senha', 
                    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));

    $rs = $pdo->query("SELECT a.ID as USERID, a.NOME_USER, b.ID as POSTID, b.TEXTO FROM users a INNER JOIN posts b on
                     (a.ID = b.ID_USER)");
    if ($rs) {                      
        foreach($rs->fetchAll() as $row):
            printf('<p>%s disse :: %s que o usuario de ID %s postou</p>', $row['NOME_USER'], $row['TEXTO'], $row['USERID']);
        endforeach;
    } else {
        var_dump($pdo->errorInfo());
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: ++excelente resposta++ . . . . Pra ficar perfeita, pra um ignorante de SQL como eu, uma pequena explicação do que está acontecendo aqui `INNER JOIN posts b on (a.ID = b.ID_USER)` ia ser genial

Comment: @brasofilo vou colocar a explicação já já ... é que eu achei outra questão que as respostas estão não muito favoravel.

Comment: Coloquei uma referencia excelente @brasofilo acho que ajuda bastante o entendimento.

Comment: A idéia é que uma resposta no [se] seja auto-suficiente e que eu não precise ir pra outro lugar pra entender. É claro que links pra documentação também aumentam, e muito, a qualidade do post. Enfim, acho sua resposta um exemplo (quase) perfeito de uma [*Resposta Canônica*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) [edit: atualizei este link].

Answer (score 3):

[**<sub>INNER JOIN EXEMPLO</sub>**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

**<sub>Baseado nas suas tabelas</sub>**

```
SELECT * FROM posts
INNER JOIN users ON posts.id = users.id WHERE users.id = 1
```

**<sub>Resultado da QUERY</sub>**

```
array(
    'id'    => '1'
    'nome'  => 'Eu'
    'texto' => 'Meu texto digitado'
)
```

> Evite usar (SELECT *), defina os campos que você vai usar declarando: (SELECT ID , NOME ... FROM)